# Color choice pills for new user-introduced choices in List column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, choice-field

I'm fairly new to Lists and I'm trying to create a list with projects and stuff. To fill it I'm using PowerApps so I can easily share with co-workers and present stuff to them at the same time.

My main problem is this: one of my columns is a choice column that is using pills. I know that I can customize the colors of the choices I set previously, but every time another user adds a new option for this column the color is set up as blank (I know this is the default set up for the column).

I want to know if it could be possible to somehow "auto-assign" new colors to new options created by users. I imagine some kind of JSON code would be necessary. As far as I've seen all this code resort to this kind of answers https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/blob/master/column-samples/generic-issuestatus-pill/generic-issuestatus-pill.json and it is hardcoded as you need to manually assign possible options and colors and I'm looking for a way to do this automatically.

Comment: As you don't know what will be the text in future, it will be difficult to automate this. However, you can easily set the default/same color for all new choices using JSON.

Comment: Isn't there a way to somehow use `possible_options[index]` or something like that so that I don't need to know the text?

Comment: I don't think so, you cannot fetch all choice options in JSON formatting.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your time!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't know what will be the text value for new option added by other users in future, it will be difficult to automate this.

However, you can easily set the default/same color for all new choices using JSON.

For this, you can use same JSON and change the classes for condition which does not match with any of predefined options for choice column.